# print outcome using one print command

Tags: python, printing, concatenation

below is my python programme where I am printing random numbers. What I want to do is print using only one print command.

```
import random

x = list(range(1,100))
y = list(range(1,100))

x = random.sample(x,6)
y = random.sample(y,1)

print("I think the lottery's winning numbers are ",x)
print('\nand the powerball should be ', y)
```

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  In particular, we expect you to access existing documentation and examples before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Python's got you covered! It's easy as abc:

```
print("I think the lottery's winning numbers are {}\nand the powerball should be {}".format(x, y))
```

Notice how with such a simple way of placing variables into strings you can easily fit in as many {}'s as you want.

This may and certainly will come in handy in the future for more complex tasks. For example, you could use this input method to check if a certain array of subdomains exist in a domain:

```
http.request('GET','https://pagetorequest.com/{}.php'.format(subdomains_to_check[index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("I think the lottery's winning numbers are {} \n and the powerball should be {}".format(x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print it like this:

```
print(f"I think the lottery's winning numbers are {x} and the powerball should be {y}")
```

adding f before "str" allows to add variables directly in the string using {variable}